# Is there any replacement for putty

Tags: windows, shell, putty

Is there any nice looking terminal with more features and sexy looks than putty?

I find it very boring.

Comment: What features do you want?

Comment: isn't putty for windows ? else you could use whatever terminal you wanted.

Comment: putty is solving my needs but just curious to know if there are some programs like that . i am using windows

Comment: See related question http://serverfault.com/questions/191140/best-ssh-program-for-windows/191142#191142

Comment: Putty Connection Manager (puttycm) adds a lot of features to Putty, such as tabbed connections and a whole lot of other things.

Comment: @Moorage: Have you tried Silly Putty? :D

Comment: What about `cygwin` with `ssh` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, it's not just a simple terminal like PuTTY, but I'm hugely fond of [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/en/) - it has tabs, a good amount of *nix native plugins on Windows, multiple terminals and you can use it just like any Linux terminal. The more recent builds also do SSH X forwarding and quite a few other interesting things.

Unlike PuTTY though, you'd need to use SSH from CLI to connect to a system via SSH.

[image]

Comment: Btw, mobaXterm uses a modified version of [mintty](http://mintty.googlecode.com) as its terminal component, which in turn is derived from PuTTY.

Comment: and cygwin and... the main advantage to it, to me is that its a single executable and can be popped on a thumbdrive ;p

Comment: Actually with Mobaxterm you can setup favorites and just like in putty you can double click and it will open a new tab with that connection. While you can still use the CLI to connect, I find having that list of favorites makes my life easier.

Answer (score 11):

My choice would be the [ZOC SSH/Telnet Terminal](http://www.emtec.com/zoc)

Looks very sexy to me and has more feature than I ever needed (and I needed a lot).

[image]

Comment: Upvote for using the word "sexy" to describe a piece of software.

Answer (score 6):

[Kitty](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/)

- An icon for each session
- Transparency
- Roll-up
- Always visible
- Background image

Comment: Yep, Kitty, coupled with SuperPuTTY for multi-tabbed/windowing https://github.com/phendryx/superputty

Comment: Kitty happens to have much better "scripting" capabilities than Putty. Which becomes very useful on Windows machines to go through multiple SSH gateways.  On linux you would use `expect`for this.

Answer (score 2):

It's the other way round (may be I'm biased): putty is the windows replacement for linux/unix `ssh`.

So if you just type `ssh myaccount@server`, you have a terminal emulator session to the node `server`.  What I mean is that putty makes up for the lack of `ssh` command under Windows standard installation.

Having said that, I do understand what you mean and have better answers.

- For one thing putty works perfectly well with [wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) if you really miss putty or if you are looking for a common toolset between Linux and Windows.
- I'm told there *is* also a native putty binary (credits to @Journeyman Geek)
- There are plenty of alternative terminal emulator for Linux, the vast majority of them support the SSH protocol.  I would recommend [Terminator](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/) for all its nice features like splitting windows horizontally and/or vertically.

Comment: there IS a native linux build of putty - but its one of those 'if you need to ask' things ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, your right. It sometimes help when you have to share ssh tunneling commands with non linux developers (for instance in a Maven POM).

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple I came accross that you might find more appealing. I have to say though that if you find PuTTY boring you're not a geek!

[SecureCRT](http://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/index.html)

[image: securecrt]

[Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier)

[image: Tunnelier]

Answer (score 1):

There's also [Cygwin mintty](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/) and [Tera Term](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA002416/teraterm.html), which are handy at times. Mintty is useful if you happen to use the Cygwin environment. Tera Term is nice because it keeps the configuration in a config file rather than in the registry.

[image]

Comment: Mintty stores its config in a file rather than the registry as well.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found a terminal which could be used as a replacement for PuTTY, called **[ClearTerminal](http://www.clearconnex.com/content/clearterminal)**. It's free, seems fairly simple and easy to use, and at the same time has many good features which are not freely available otherwise.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's [PuTTY Tray: Redux by Toby Simmons](http://www.simmonsconsulting.com/puttytray) (last updated in February this year) and [PuTTY Tray by Chris West](http://puttytray.goeswhere.com) (last updated a couple of days ago).

I think there are no practical differences between these two. Both are based on the original PuTTY Tray by Barry Haanstra.

Or would everyone agree about the differences?

Answer (score 0):

I've started using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) instead of PuTTY.  ssh, scp, and a bunch of other features work right out of the box and now that I'm so used to the bash, I find myself preferring it to cmd.exe.

It's probably not really what you're looking for in terms of eye candy, but it hits a sweet spot for a programmer like me with its functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I started using KiTTY and mRemoteNG. KiTTY http://www.9bis.net/kitty/?page=Download is an updated PuTTY and mRemoteNG is a session manager: http://www.mremoteng.org/download
I have read reviews and my own experience so far is this is better than plain putty or its manager. Give this a try and let me know if you find issues or interesting features we can all use. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

"Link only answers are bad"

http://alternativeto.net/software/putty/?platform=linux since you tagged it with Linux, but in your comments you say you are using Windows, so http://alternativeto.net/software/putty/?platform=windows

Comment: sorry for that i tagged linux as putty was used to link linux systems

Comment: that looks like a link only answer ;p

Comment: Should be a comment